# why there is two instances of a singleton with Google Guice dependency injection framework

Tags: java, singleton, guice

There’s 2 Singleton instances, both created by Google Guice, in my application.

How’s that even possible?

The binding is done as follow:

```
bind(Foo.class).to(FooImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```

Comment: There's a lot of things that could be going on. Are you sure you are installing the module that provides the binding? How are you injecting the instance (let's see the code)?

Comment: I can't show the code, but the initialization module bind a thousand of other Singleton classes and there is no problem.. This module is installed for sure!

Comment: Are you injecting Foo or FooImpl?

Comment: Do you have more than one injector?

Comment: FooImpl is the implementation of Foo interface. So, in my code, I use the general interface but Google Guice is actually injecting the implementation..

Comment: Yes, there is only one injector in the project.. I don't figure out why this happen..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here was the binding declaration.

We fixed it by replacing the binding declaration to:

```
bind(FooImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
bind(Foo.class).to(FooImpl.class);
```

Comment: Weird! Is this actually something that follows from the definitions of those methods, or is this a bug?

Comment: According to http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Scopes, It's the source class which is binded by Guice, and not the target. So, I probably had in my project two class which were the implementation of the interface. So, the problem was to bind the implementation as a singleton. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002935/whats-the-difference-between-these-two-binding-declarations-with-google-guice

Comment: Since "scopes apply to the bound type [...],, not the type that satisfies that binding", i think your original declaration bound `Foo` as a singleton, but if there was another binding type that `FooImpl` could satisfy (perhaps `FooImpl` itself, or another interface that it implements), then that would have evoked as second instance.