# what's the difference between these two binding declarations with Google Guice?

Tags: java, guice

What's the difference between

```
bind(FooImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
bind(Foo.class).to(FooImpl.class);
```

and

```
bind(Foo.class).to(FooImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```

With Google Guice?

**edit:**

The second declaration create two instances on Singleton in a project I am working on.
[Reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001920/why-there-is-two-instances-of-a-singleton-with-google-guice-dependency-injection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [reference](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Scopes) to Google Guice documentation:

> In linked bindings, scopes apply to the binding source, not the
>   binding target. Suppose we have a class Applebees that implements both
>   Bar and Grill interfaces. These bindings allow for two instances of
>   that type, one for Bars and another for Grills:

```
bind(Bar.class).to(Applebees.class).in(Singleton.class);
bind(Grill.class).to(Applebees.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

> This is because the scopes apply to the bound type (Bar, Grill), not
>   the type that satisfies that binding (Applebees). To allow only a
>   single instance to be created, use a `@Singleton` annotation on the
>   declaration for that class. Or add another binding:

```
bind(Applebees.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

So, It's possible to have two instances of `FooImpl` in the second way but not with the first way of writing the binding.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Both will bind `Foo` to an instance of `FooImpl` in the `SINGLETON` scope.

Comment: There is a difference, in a project I am working on, we just discover that the second instance caused 2 instances of the singleton.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, you appear to have the correct answer. BTW, if you had mentioned what the difference in the result of the two approaches was, it may have helped figure out whether/how they were different.